# SQL counting by groups

Tags: mysql, select, join, nested

I have a table that looks like this

```
id  name answer   question
1   john  correct 1
1   john  correct 2
1   john  correct 3
1   john  wrong   4
2   lee   wrong   1
2   lee   correct 2
2   lee   correct 3
3   ana   correct 1
3   ana   wrong   2
```

I want to be able to get a list of all unique users, and see how many questions they have correct and how many are wrong.

I tried something like this but I cant seem to make it work:

```
SELECT id, user_id, name, question_id, (select count(answer) from table where answer = 'CORRECT') as correct, (select count(answer) from table where answer= 'WRONG') as wrong FROM table GROUP BY user_id
```

Can someone help me get me on the right track? thanks

Comment: Please go back over your old questions and set them to answered (where possible)

Comment: Also, it's inadvisable to use textual values like "correct", etc. What happens if someone gets the case wrong, or misspells it?

Comment: CORRECT and WRONG are only flags in the DB for internal back end use. Nobody ever types in any data

Comment: Therefore you'd be better to call the field "Correct" and use 0 and 1 values. This will take up less storage and be quicker for your queries. It may only be a practice database, but it's better to get into good practice now.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
SELECT name, answer, COUNT(*) FROM yourtablenamehere GROUP BY name, answer
```

Comment: thanks so much, the only question I have is... how can i have the count of correct and wrong answers in the same array node, so I can have unique users in that array?

Comment: I know what you mean - but I don't know of a way you can get the results of just one column ('answer') to appear in two different ways in the query result.  Personally, I would do that part at an application level.  I use PHP, so when processing the results of the query above using mysql_fetch_array() (for example) I would then store the results in a local array key'd by the 'name' field.

Answer (score 1):

You do what you want with conditional sums:

```
select name, sum(case when answer = 'correct' then 1 else 0 end) as correct,
       sum(case when answer = 'wrong' then 1 else 0 end) as wrong
from table t
group by name
```

Comment: I would adjust the query to rely on the ID (but carry the name forward too) as what if you have 3 different IDs, but all the name "John"

Answer (score 0):

for MySQL it could be like this:

```
SELECT user_id, name,SUM(IF(answer='correct',1,0)) AS correct,SUM(IF(answer='wrong',1,0)) as wrong FROM table GROUP BY user_id
```